# Como cambiar el color de letras en php utilizando style: color

Tags: php, html

recién estoy empezado en el mundo del desarrollo web con php. Estoy haciendo una calculadora de índice de masa corporal, pero quiero cambiar el color de la variable $resultado de manera dinámica, dependiendo del resulatdo dentro de un div pero no lo consigo.

">Resultado:

Si creo una nueva etiqueta php sin el div si consigo que se imprima con un echo pero en color negro.

Les dejo un fragmento del código

```html
                  <?php

if ( isset($_POST['peso']) && isset($_POST['altura']) && is_numeric($_POST['peso']) && is_numeric($_POST['altura']) ) {

  $peso = $_POST['peso'];
  $altura = $_POST['altura'];

  $imc = $peso / ($altura*$altura);
  $imc = round($imc,1);


  if ($imc<18.5){
    $resultado = "Peso inferior al normal";
    $color="orange";
  }

  if ($imc >= 18.5 && $imc < 24.9){
    $resultado = "Normal";
    $color="green";
  }

  if ($imc >= 24.9 && $imc < 29.9){
    $resultado = "Peso superior al normal";
    $color="yellow";
  }

  if ($imc>30){
    $resultado = "Obesidad";
    $color="orange";
  }

}

?>
                  
                  <form class="" action="index.php" method="POST" >
                    Peso (kg) <br> <input type="number" step=".01" name="peso" value="" placeholder="Tu peso en kilogramos" required ><br><br>
                    Altura (m) <br>  <input type="number" step=".01" name="altura" value="" placeholder="Tu altura en metros" required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="" value="CALCULAR">
                  </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <?php if (isset($imc)){ ?>
                    <?php echo "Tu I.M.C es de -> ".$imc; ?>
                      <br>
                      <div style="color:<?php echo $color;?>">Resultado: <? echo $resultado; ?></div>

                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
             </div><br>
```

Comment: Tu duda no se entiende, ¿puedes explicarte mejor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu calculadora funciona correctamente, el único inconveniente que puedes tener es que tu servidor no tenga habilitado el uso de short tags

Siempre lo recomendable es usar **<?php** en lugar de **<?**  siendo este ultimo una versión corta del primero, pero en algunos servidores esta deshabilitado por lo que tu código puede no funcionar cuando lo entregues al cliente.

Dicho eso, basta con agregar <?php en el echo de $resultado

```
<div style="color:<?php echo $color;?>">Resultado: <?php echo $resultado; ?></div>
```

Comment: Su respuesta fué muy acertada, muchísimas gracias amigo, ya me funciona.